# Enable Webmatrix Intellisense for PHP in .html files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, webmatrix

***Is there a way to configure WebMatrix to treat .html files the same as .php files?***

I am editing an existing site that has php code in .html files.  The site functions fine because the appropriate handler declarations are in .htaccess.  I want to use WebMatrix to edit these but would like the intellisense/formating for php to work but of course WebMatrix only recognizes them as php if they are .php extensions.  Since the production environment function this way it would make sense for the development environment to be the same. Renaming all files to .php has too high of risk for broken links.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this in the file **web.config**

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="REWRITE_TO_PHP">
        <match url=".html" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />

        <action type="Rewrite" url=".php" />
            </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  The host is Apache so there is not a web.config file.  On the local machine (running webmatrix) IIS is not installed and I don't see a web.config file in the webmatrix path?